# Laravel Forge returning [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, sentry, laravel-forge

I have recently removed a Sentry package when I upgraded to 5.4. I have removed the alias and provider from `config/app.php` and reverted the `Exception/handler.php` file back to Laravel's original.

The application itself works as expected **locally**, but upon attempting any `artisan` command within the server (deployed through Forge), it shows:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Class
>   'Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryLaravelServiceProvider' not found

I have ran the following commands, yet the error is still persistent:

`composer dumpautoload` and
`composer clear-cache`, yet I cannot run any Artisan command.

Is there another cache location, or additional action I should take to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually remove `bootstrap/cache` directory and then `mkdir cache`.